# Kamailio IMS Diameter

Tags: kamailio, ims

With changes in Kamailio.cfg  Richard Good on Dec 17, 2014
Updated P-CSCF example with additional Rx_AAR params, incorporated[image] in kamailio.cfg, I am able to REGISTER 200 ok with Rx interface.

But I want to send AAR message only after receiving 200 ok at pcscf. Currently message sequences are

```
        CER ------->                                            
        <-------CEA
        AAR --------->                                
        <------AAA
        REGISTER--->
        <-------401
        REGISTER---->
        <----200ok
```

Screen shot is for reference.

But I want to Send AAR/AAA only after REGISTER 200ok.
Below is the Sequence:

```
        CER ------->                                            
        <-------CEA

        REGISTER--->
        <-------401
        REGISTER---->
        <----200 ok

        AAR --------->                                
        <------AAA
```

I using PCSCF as Diameter client and Seagull as a Diameter server.
I am able to REGISTER but not able to send AAR/AAA after 200 ok.(Refer picture)

Kindly let me know any other changes required in kamailio.cfg or seagull scenario.xml or some where else.
and What changes.

Answer (score 0):

Under ims_qos module, you need to edit mod.c. Here Rx_AAR_Register will be enabled by default for Register requests. If you want to enable it for Register-replies, you need to add ON_REPLY_ROUTE in that line.

By default AAR will go only for 200 OK of register requests.

Thanks, Senthil.